# Saída banda servidor MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

tenho um servidor MS SQL, com 14 databases, que variam de 2mb a 20gb.

A saída de trafego dele pela rede é em torno de 92GB/dia.

Gostaria de saber se existe como eu monitorar para saber:

- Quais databases mais consomem esse trafego.
- Quais consultas geram mais trafego (kb Vs qtd. requisições)

Não encontrei nda específico.

Comment: Veja isso. https://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/how-to-monitor-your-sql-server-instances-and-databases/

Comment: tenho usado o monitor além de uma outra ferramenta feita por mim de trace, mas está longe de ser eficiente..essas vão ser as minhas ferramentas para o plano B, caso não ache um plano A..rs

Comment: Esse aspexSQL me parece promissor..vou fazer um teste local.